# Best performing image dimensions for +[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:]?

Tags: uikit, core-graphics, uicolor

To create a uniform shadow that spans the entire width of the screen, I'm using `+[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:]` to set a `UIView`’s `backgroundColor`. It looks perfect if I only save the image as 2 px (1 pt) wide because it repeats 320 times horizontally.

I'm wondering, does it draw faster if I make the picture slightly wider, say 10 px? What is the optimal ratio to use to get the best drawing performance while still maintaining a small (memory) image?